# how to write a for loop to add whitespaces? (JAVA)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have to make a for loop for this code and want to know how to add white spaces to each side.

```
//3. The method returns a String that contains width characters and centres the
// text within the width by adding sufficient spaces before and after the text.
//If the total number of spaces required to centre the text(i.e the total of spaces before and after)
//is an odd number the additional space should be on the left of the text. If the text is longer/wider
//the method should return only the leftmost characters of the text(i.e. it should trim text text).
public static String centre(String text, int width){

    
    int padding = width - text.length() / 2;
    

    if(padding == 0)
```

This is what i have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so.  This method uses a `StringBuilder` to contain the text.  No check for when the text matches the width is required as the loops will not engage if that happens.  Single quotes surround the text to show the spacing.

```
String text = "no spaces needed";
System.out.printf("'%s'%n", centre(text,text.length()));
text = "even on both sides";
System.out.printf("'%s'%n", centre(text,text.length()+10));
text = "extra space on left";      
System.out.printf("'%s'%n", centre(text,text.length()+11));
text = "this text is too long";      
System.out.printf("'%s'%n", centre(text,text.length()-5));
```

Prints

```
'no spaces needed'
'     even on both sides     '
'      extra space on left     '
'this text is too'


public static String centre(String text, int width){
    int len = text.length();
    // automatically adjusts for odd number of spaces on left and even on right
    int left = (width-len+1)/2;
    int right = width-len-left;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < left; i++) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    sb.append(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < right; i++) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    // return the string or a right trimmed string if the string exceeds the width.
    return sb.substring(0,width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append to a `StringBuilder` in a loop:

```java
public static String centre(String text, int width) {
    int diff = width - text.length();
    if (diff <= 0) {
        // nothing needs to be done
        return text;
    }
    // right side is rounded down
    int paddingRight = diff / 2;
    // left side gets the remainder
    int paddingLeft = diff - paddingRight;
    // start building the string
    StringBuilder builder;
    // add the left padding
    for (int i = 0; i < paddingLeft; i ++) {
        builder.append(' ');
    }
    // add the actual text
    builder.append(text);
    // add the right padding
    for (int i = 0; i < paddingRight; i ++) {
        builder.append(' ');
    }
    // get a string from the builder
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

```java
public static String centre(String text, int width) {
        // Calculate the max padding length for left padding.
        int overrall_padding = width - text.length();
        int padlen = (overrall_padding >> 1) + (width & 1);
        // Create the padding as character array.
        char[] padding = new char[padlen];
        // Fill the array with spaces
        for(int i=0;i<padding.length;i++)padding[i]=' ';
        // Create a builder.
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        // Append the at the begining as left padding.
        builder.append(padding);
        // append the text
        builder.append(text);
        // append the right padding. (note: the reuse of padding, division of width by 2)
        builder.append(padding, 0, overrall_padding >> 1);
        // Return
        return builder.toString();

    }
```

Note the reuse of `char[]` buffer just to optimize the speed while maintaining efficiency.

Comment: The OP said the requirement was to use for loops.

Comment: @WJS I might have missed that a bit but i corrected it.

Answer (score -1):

You may find this interesting as well. I have applied **String.format()** to generate padding. str.substring() is used to trim()

Syntax:

```
String.format("%[L]s", str);
```

Example

```
String.format("%3s", ""); // Generates 3 spaces
String.format("%5s", ""); // Generates 5 spaces
String.format("%3s%s%3s", "", "Hello", ""); // ***Hello*** ; *=space
```

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pad-a-string-in-java/

Code:

```
class Solution{
    public static String centre(String text, int width){
        int length = text.length();
        if(length >= width)
            return text.substring(0, width);        // trimming to width
        else{
            int padding = width - length;
            if(padding == 1)
                return String.format(" %s", text);  // adding single space to the left
            else{
                int padLeft, padRight;
                padLeft = padRight = padding >> 1;  // dividing by 2
                if((padding & 1) == 1)              // if odd number the adding extra 1 to left
                    padLeft += 1;
                return String.format("%" + padLeft + "s%s%" + padRight + "s", "", text, "");
            }            
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(centre("Hello", 4));
        System.out.println(centre("Hello", 5));
        System.out.println(centre("Hello", 6));
        System.out.println(centre("Hello", 7));
        System.out.println(centre("Hello", 8));
    }
}
```

Output (* for visualizing spaces):

```
Hell Hello
*Hello
*Hello*
**Hello*
```